# Как исправить проблему в битности при компиляции?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake

Я компилирую библиотеку [QHTTPEngine](https://github.com/nitroshare/qhttpengine), на Windows 7 64-bit для qt 5.7. У меня установлен Visual Studio 2015 Community. В Qt Creator мне доступны такие компиляторы: `Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015 64 bit(amd 64)` и `64bit 2(x86_amd64)`, а также `MinQW 32-bit`.

Делаю все, как описано в Readme. Установил `CMake`, добавил в Path, добавил в Path также папку `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin`
Запустил `vcvarsall.bat` с параметром `x86_amd64`, чтобы настроить переменные среды. Потом запускаю в командной строке `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..` - все генерируется. Потом, когда я запускаю `nmake`, вылазит куча ошибок от `cl.exe` с кодами `"0x2"` и `"0xffffff"`. Уже второй день не могу установить.

При этом, все собирается и компилируется, если в bat файл передать параметр `x86`, но тогда Qt Creator выдает ошибку `QHttpEngine.lib(QHttpEngine.dll):-1: ошибка: LNK1112: тип компьютера модуля "X86" противоречит типу целевого компьютера "x64"`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить проблему. Хочу запустить хотя бы простейший example.

Comment: 1) попробуйте очистить решение(В Qt creator это бывает часто лечит проблемы)                                                                                                       2) Я бы на вашем месте сделал следующее, переустановите Qt creator и внимательно смотрите на то, что отмечено для установки, есть такая хрень, что он НЕ УСТАНАВЛИВАЕТ Компоновщик по умолчанию, потыкайте по разделам и убедитесь что все стоит, что вам нужно                                                                                                 3) Qt creator не знает о том что вы что-то собрали, можно еще попробо

Comment: вать посмотреть внимательно настройки сборки и добавить использованный вами компилятор

Comment: @Xambey Да Qt Creator здесь вообще почти не причем - ему то нужно всего лишь скормить скомпилированную библиотеку. Ошибки возникают в командной строке, при компиляции, при запуске команды `nmake`

Comment: эм... ну тогда проверьте makefile, возможно с ним проблемы

Comment: @Xambey хех, вполне возможно. Но я не знаю, что там может быть не так. Да и make file cmake генерирует нормально. Тут, похоже проблема именно с компилятором. А вот в чем именно - это и есть вопрос.

Comment: Если не можете разобраться со сборкой 64-х бит через nmake, тогда разберитесь как сменить битность компилятора при сборке в Qt. У Вас должен там быть компилятора для x86, его там просто не может не быть, а если его нет, то существует какая-то проблема с установкой. Вот как у меня выглядит список доступных компиляторов QtCreator: http://screencast.com/t/9nAWWPSREed

Comment: @ixSci, У меня в настройках есть примерно те же компиляторы, что и у вас(http://i.imgur.com/GgX8k33.png). Но вот в настройках проекта 32-битные почему-то отсутствуют: http://i.imgur.com/mG42Yqh.png Или битность в проекте qt меняется не здесь?

Comment: Под кнопкой «Добавить» есть кнопка «Manage Kits..»(не знаю как оно там по-русски), где Вы сможете добавить kit с нужным компилятором, который впоследствии Вы сможете выбирать для компиляции. Только нужно убедиться, в таком случае, что у Вас установлена 32-х битная версия Qt, иначе не взлетит.